# Add child nodes to treeview without using foreach

Tags: c#, wpf

WPF treeview. Is there a way to add a child node to an already populated treeview without having to run in a for/foreach to check the header then converting that into an TreeViewIem ?

```
private void AddChildNode(string _rootNode, string _childeNode)
    {
        foreach (TreeViewItem node in tvSQLTasks.Items)
        {
            if (node.Header.Equals(_rootNode))
            {
                node.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = _childeNode });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why did the question get down voted? I googled the hell out of it and haven't come up with anything.

Comment: Why do you need anything else?  What's the problem with what you have?

Comment: @Tsukasa, don't you use a model/collection as data source for the TreeView?

Comment: adding 200+ nodes and always having to loop the main collection seems like there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: @Tsukasa Build up your tree structure outside of the Treeview, using whatever data structures make sense, and then when you have the entire tree based structure *then* copy all of the items, all at once, over to the treeview.  That's a lot more efficient, and is generally a better design, than adding each item one at a time to the UI.

Comment: Actually, having a an data model (collection, some other data source) as ItemsSource is the "Better Way"(TM) ;) If you need to add a child to an item by a propery/name, you can back it by a dictionary, for example. Easier, more flexible, better performance than messing around directly with the the logical tree of the TreeView control...

Comment: Servy/elgonzo thanks for the advice, that sounds a lot better than looping it.

Comment: +1 for googled the hell out of it :) :) :) I didnt know you can google the hell out of something.

Answer (score 1):

Create an `ObservableCollection` collection of objects, populate the collection with objects representing what treeview is supposed to display and bind that collection to `ItemSource` property of your TV.

Binding is the only proper way to go about populating your treeview with items in WPF and if you use the `ObservableCollection` you'll have the added benefit of items added to/removed from the collection "automagically" appearing in/disappearing from your TV without writing any additional code.

Depending on how complex your treeview needs to be you might have to use `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and `ItemStyleSelector`.